# A quadratic trinomial that generates only prime numbers of the form $4m+1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It is known that Euler's polynomials $\,n^2+n+p\,$ ($p\,$ prime) represent a prime for $\,n=0,\,...,\,p-2\,$ if and only if the field $\,Q (\sqrt{1-4p})\,$ has class number $\,h=1$.

The best trinomial of such kind is $\,n^2+n+41$.

> **But what we can say about quadratic trinomials that generate, for
>   consecutive values of their integer variable, only prime numbers of
>   the form $\,4m+1$?**

The best I could find out is the following trinomial:
$$p(n)=4\cdot(32\cdot(21-n)-n^2)+1$$
that generates prime numbers of the form $\,4m+1\,$ for $\,n=0,\,...,\,14$.

At the $2$-nd place, I would put the trinomial:
$$p(n)=4\cdot(n\cdot(64+n)-1171)+3$$
that generates (eventually in absolute value) prime numbers of the form $\,4m+1\,$ for $\,n=1,\,...,\,14\,$ and of the form $\,4m+3\,$ for $\,n=15,\,...,\,28$.

Every suggestion is well accepted.

Many thanks.

[ This question have been also posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356000/a-quadratic-trinomial-that-generates-only-prime-numbers-of-the-form-4m1) ]

Comment: Please do not crosspost.

Comment: Is the polynomial allowed to produce primes of the form $4k+3$ later ?

Comment: $$f(x)=8x^2-16x+37$$ produces only numbers of the form $4k+1$ and is prime for $0\le x\le 15$

Comment: $$f(x)=36x^2 + 168x + 373$$ produces only numbers of the form $4k+1$ and is prime for $-6\le x\le 22$ and many other integer $x$

Answer (score 2):

$$f=36x^2 - 192x + 433$$ produces only integers of the form $\ 4k+1\ $ and for integers in then range $\ [0,36]\ $, it is only composite for $\ 28\ $ and $\ 29\ $. In particular, it is prime for integer $\ x\ $ with $\ 0\le x\le 27\ $

I restricted the first two coefficients to be divisible by $\ 4\ $ and the last being of the form $\ 4k+1\ $, which ensures that only values of the form $\ 4k+1\ $ can occur. With those restrictions and with coefficients with absolute value not larger than $\ 600\ $, this is the best possible polynomial.